# Browser freezes for 4-5 seconds until Vue component finishes loading

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component: `task.vue` which generates a list of tasks, and an `epic.vue` component which is the parent of `task.vue`, so for each `epic.vue` I generate it's tasks list from `task.vue`.
The problem is that when I reload the page, the browser freezes for 4-5 seconds until the `task.vue` component renders completely.

Everytime I reload the page I have an ajax that fetches all the data from an api function. It returns a nested array containing epics(folders in folders), each with it's own set of tasks. It is indeed a big array, could contain 1000+ records.

Is there a way to fix the freezing of the browser while the `task.vue` component loads ?

In my `epic.vue` I simply pass a `prop` to `task.vue` component containing all the task that current epic has.

My array structure and vue rendering is exactly like: https://vuejs.org/examples/tree-view.html.

Comment: Are you using synchronous AJAX calls?

Comment: @ceejayoz no, the ajax calls are async by default

Answer (score 2):

If the loading time is directly related to the number of records you're loading then you could consider loading an initial chunk (e.g. 100 or so) to allow for a quick render and then lazy load the rest in immediately or as needed in same-sized chunks.